# Coded UI assertion treats two items in one page as same one

Tags: user-interface, testing, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests, gui-testing

I want to utilize Coded UI's adding assertion function to detect system Error Message.
However, I found when I was adding assertion to locate the line I want to detect the Error Message, if two rows' object name are same. Adding assertion function will treat them as same assertion. 
Looks like the "Object" name is the keyword Coded UI is using to detect. All the other "Status" "Result" and "Error Message" are not attributes for Coded UI to distinguish the item.

What should I do? Thank you!

This is my work project GUI. I have to make into Excel to illustrate. And the blue box is the smallest box appeared, when I droped assertion cursor to the GUI.

[The GUI I want to test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YIwDv.png)

Comment: please provide a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: If you call UITestControl.GetChildren on the highlighted row, what items do you get in the UITestControlCollection it returns? Possibly you will need to dig deeper into your UITestControls. Recursion could be useful for that purpose. What type of project are you testing? It's not clear to me from your question.

Comment: Also, take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52627759/codedui-findmatchingcontrols-works-10-of-the-time-but-usually-returns-about/52643633#52643633) Q&A, if you are interested in a recursive method in combination with GetChildren.