# Assert all the li in the div in coded UI test

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

```
<div class="validation-summary-errors">
    <span>Please check the following entries:</span>
    <ul>
        <li>Please select a client account</li>
        <li>Please select a beneficiary account</li>
    </ul>
</div>

public virtual T VerifyAmountValidationMessages()
{
    HtmlDiv error = new HtmlDiv(_browserWindow);

    error.SearchProperties[HtmlDiv.PropertyNames.Class] = "validation-summary-errors";
    var errors = error.FindMatchingControls();
    var errorLi = error.GetChildren()[0];
    foreach (var item in errors)
    {
        Assert.IsTrue(item.GetProperty("InnerText").ToString().Contains("Please check the following entries:\r\nPlease select a client account\r\nPlease select a beneficiary account"));
    }
    return (T)this;
}
```

How can I iterate all the lis and assert the inner text of each Li, with the getChildren I can access the span element individually but I want to access the Li individually? Right Now I am asserting the whole text which is not the correct approach at all.

Answer (score 0):

The ul element would be `errors.GetChildren()[0];` you would them loop over its children.

```
<div class="validation-summary-errors"> 
    <span>Please check the following entries:</span> 
    <ul> 
        <li>Please select a client account</li> 
        <li>Please select a beneficiary account</li> 
    </ul> 
</div>
```

---

```
public virtual T VerifyAmountValidationMessages()
{
    HtmlDiv error = new HtmlDiv(_browserWindow);
    error.SearchProperties[HtmlDiv.PropertyNames.Class] = "validation-summary-errors"; 
    var errors = error.FindMatchingControls(); 
    var errorul = error.GetChildren()[1];
    foreach (var item in errors
    { 
        // check individual li items
    } 
    return (T)this; 
}
```

This would seem to be a brittle test though, consider if any changes are made to how errors are displayed, you'll have to rewrite the test.

Comment: Thanks for the help, then How should I verify this?

Comment: IMO your first method was on the right track, I would just use the reference to `error` (the div with the `validation-summary-errors` class) and make sure it contained all the messages you need it to contain.

Comment: Sorry to say but I didn't get you.

Comment: You don't want to check for specific constructs (i.e. the `<ul>`, `<li>`, etc) when testing, it leads to brittle tests that fail whenever a design change is made to the page, so in your case I think the test should check that element with `validation-summary-errors` class on it contains the error messages you're interested in.

Comment: Got your point but don't know how to do this :D Anyway thank you for the help.

Comment: Using hardcoded indexes makes your test brittle too. Look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52627759/codedui-findmatchingcontrols-works-10-of-the-time-but-usually-returns-about/52643633#52643633). It's a general purpose recursive `GetChildren` method that will get you the whole structure beneath a given object. Since `HtmlDiv` is derived from `UITestControl`, this should work. You could adjust the `foreach` loop so you only get the data you need.