# Is there a way to keep Coded UI Test Builder tool from hiding Visual Studio?

Tags: coded-ui-tests

One of the many "features" that annoy me about using CodedUI for test automation is that the Test Builder tool hides Visual Studio when you open it to try to spy an element. This is extraordinarily annoying when you're trying to maintain legacy scripts that aren't working correctly. How do I compare the existing location properties of an element to see if they are compatible with the current state of the application? Currently, I have take a snapshot of the CUITB window, close the tool and then paste the result into something else to compare.

This is especially infuriating because the properties found by the CUITB have little correlation with other spy tools like Inspect, Snoop, etc. rendering those tools unusable for hand coding Coded UI scripts.

Is there a way to configure VS or the test builder tool to NOT hide VS while spying on screen elements? If this is possible, I haven't been able to figure out how to do it.

Comment: Not really a answer to your question about hiding, but I can offer you an alternative without using the CUITB. Take a look at the function in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52627759/codedui-findmatchingcontrols-works-10-of-the-time-but-usually-returns-about/52643633#52643633), it loads a parent control and all its children in a object tree in a recursive way. If you adjust the function, you could e.g. output the location of the elements you want to compare. If this is a sufficient solution for your problem, I'd write it as a answer.

Comment: Can you run two copies of Visual Studio? Can you use two monitors?