# How to query the title of the current UI-Window that's tested in a Coded-UI-Test?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, coded-ui-tests, ui-testing

Can any of you tell me how I can get the title of the window (UI-Control) that is currently open during my UI-Test? (Coded-UI-Test with Visual Studio in Visual Basic .NET)

I searched for a while now, but I couldn't find anything unfortunately.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Best regards
Simon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could search for the automationId for that control and take a look at the properties from the control you found. In your coded ui test, you can check if the control exists, whenever you expect it to be available.
Take a look at this screenshot, it's data from a explorer window I captured with Inspect.exe.
[image]

As you can see, in this case, in my testscript, I need to search for AutomationId "TitleBar" and use the value from the properties LegacyIAccessible.Value or Value.Value in order to get the window title.

Since you are working with coded UI, the easiest way to get your hands on that control is by using the build in coded ui test builder from Visual Studio and add the control to a UIMap. No need to record a new test. You can find the instructions [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/5d6808b5-26d1-44c9-85c7-2b2bcea7de85/how-to-add-controls-to-uimap-without-recording). The answer from SudheerUppada is the usefull bit. If you don't like working with UIMaps, you can copy the usefull bits of generated code to your test script and afterwards remove the control from the UIMap.

Here's a screenshot of the same ui control, taken from the test builder:
[image]
In this example, the window title is available trough the DisplayText property.

There are also more generic ways of finding the current window title. This involves iterating on any given control untill you have the upmost parent control. You will need to write a method that involves the use of `UITestControl.GetParent()`. It will probably need to be recursive in order to get the parent from the parent from the parent from..... You get the idea right? Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52627759/codedui-findmatchingcontrols-works-10-of-the-time-but-usually-returns-about/52643633#52643633) answer, it's roughly the same but for child controls. You can convert C# code to vb code with online tools like [this one](https://converter.telerik.com/) from telerik.

There is the possibility that the control and/or the title from that control won't be accessible to your coded ui test. That's a other problem. If that is the case in your situation, there are many resources available on the internet which describe what needs to be done... or you could post a new question about it :-).